# JAX-RS and Apache CXF

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I am new to Webservices, I am confused about the JAX-RS and apache CXF

What i read is that JAX-RS is API  and Apache CXF is implementation of JAX-RS

JAX-RS is not specification , Is it possible to direclty use JAX-RS to build REST services?

Please correct me if I am wrong

Regards

Answer (score 2):

[JAX-RS](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) is a specification. The binaries provided by it only contain `Interface` definitions but no implementations.

The default implementation of JAX-RS is [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/). It provides implementations plus additional features.

[Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/) and [Restlet](http://restlet.org/) are other implementations of JAX-RS that provide different additional features.